# Passing arguments with next line to C program

Tags: c, command, arguments, eof

I am trying to run a C program in Ubuntu via command prompt, I can run successfully using

```
./aaa<arg_file.txt

Content of arg_file.txt
a
bb
ccc
```

It displays the result successfully, but this time I do not want to use the txt file to pass the parameters, instead I want to pass all the arguments using one single line, how can I represent the next line character in the argument field?

Thanks all for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell is Bash or compatible, use the `<<[SENTINEL]` syntax:

```
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ cat <<EOF
> abc
> def
> ghi
> EOF
abc
def
ghi
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass with spaces inbetween like

```
./aaa a bb ccc
```

In C program, `argv[0]` will be ur exe name. then

```
argv[1] = "a"
argv[2] = "bb"
argv[3] = "ccc"
```

will be there.

Comment: Thanks Jeyaram, but some of the arguments has space.
Like
a a a (one argument)